# Android, диспетчеризация

Tags: android

Сравнительно недавно в Android. Начал читать литературу по `RxJava`, и на каждой странице попадается слово `диспетчеризация`. Можно в двух словах, что это значит?

В литературе упоминается в контексте оптимизации кода. Например, если мы ассинхронно тянем данные которые можно тянуть синхронно(например одно значение из SP), то это ухудшит производительность из - за увеличенных расходов на диспетчеризацию.

**UPD:** Я бы не спрашивал если бы оно нормально загуглилось. Пока что в моём представлении говоря о диспетчеризации имеют ввиду цепочку системных(?)методов, которая вызывается между какими - то двумя выбранными методами, и чем больше таких вызовов тем больше потери производительности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо смотреть в контексте, если книга о rxJava речь идет о диспетчеризации процессов, на который может повлиять диспетчер и планировщики. Если задача уже асинхронна, то нет необходимости загонять её в отдельный пул потоков, это приведет к расходом на переключение контектса, переключение потоков и диспетчеризацию, что примерно в книге и будут повторять.

Немного своими словами о диспетчеризации. Процессы имеют определенный приоритет, ядро может переключать контекст на процесс с наивысшим приоритетом. Создаётся очередь планирования процессов, когда ядро переключает задачу на выполнение пересчитываются приоритеты, это хоть и ничего не значит в рамках вселенной, но для несколько миллиардов вычислений в секунду мб очень ощутимо, а современные девайсы могут легко этим похвастаться.